# How do I navigate between routes without using navigation prop?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I'm currently trying to call the `DrawerOpen` route(Example #1) from a screen(Example #3) that is inside a `StackNavigator` that is rendered as `<ProductStack>` inside a component(Example #3).

Inside that Stack, I need that a button that can be able to access the `DrawerOpen`, but the navigation that I have on that page, can't access that `DrawerOpen` route.

Is there any way to access (and call) any route from any component of my app without depending on the navigation prop?

Here is my drawer component (Example #1):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

import { DrawerNavigator } from 'react-navigation'

import ProductEntryScreen from './../productEntry/screen'
import InvoiceInScreen from './../invoiceIn/screen'

const InvoiceInEntry = { screen: InvoiceInScreen}
const ProductEntry = {
  screen: ProductEntryScreen,
  navigationOptions: {
    title: 'Entrada de produto'
  }
}

const Drawer = DrawerNavigator({
  ProductEntry,
  InvoiceInEntry
})

export default Drawer
```

Here is the wrapper component (Example #2, also it is imported on #1 as `ProductEntryScreen`):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

import {
  StackNavigator,
} from 'react-navigation'

import InfoScreen from './info/screen'
/* Other imports omitted due to brevity */

import * as ProductEntryActions from './actions'
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'

const Info = {
  screen: InfoScreen,
  navigationOptions: {
    title: 'Entrada de produto'
  }
}

/* Other routes omitted due to brevity */

const ProductStack = StackNavigator({
  Info,
  /* Other routes omitted due to brevity */
},{
  initialRouteName: 'Info',
})

class ProductEntryScreen extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.getBlocks()
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <ProductStack />
    )
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => bindActionCreators(ProductEntryActions, dispatch)

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(ProductEntryScreen)
```

Now the screen (Example #3):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

/* Imports ommited */

export default class ProductEntryScreen extends Component {
  static navigationOptions = ({navigation, screenProps}) => ({
    headerLeft: (
      <MenuButton
        onClick={() => {
          // This used to work without wrapping ProductStack in a component
          // but I need it to be a component
          navigation.navigate('DrawerOpen')
        }
      />
    ),
  })

  render() {
    return (
      <View></View>
    )
  }
}
```

If I `export default ProductStack` on #2 without creating a component (also losing that function on `componentDidMount`), the navigation to `DrawerOpen` on #3 works like charm. But I need to call that function, and also know a way to call `DrawerOpen` without having to depend on the `navigation` prop.

Comment: Please add [mcve] to give more context to your question. In current state its hard to understand what you are doing and trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using redux or something similar then you can create an action to route for you. If not you can use `NavigationActions`:

```
import { NavigationActions } from 'react-navigation';

const navigateAction = NavigationActions.navigate({
  routeName: 'Profile',
  params: {},
});

this.props.navigation.dispatch(navigateAction);
```

Comment: Have you tried calling a `DrawerOpen` route using that method? I have already tried, no success...